# Multiple window functions over the same partition

Tags: sql

This works fine:

```
SUM(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) AS TotalRevenue
```

How can I make this work?

```
SUM(Revenue) - SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) AS TotalProfit
```

In other words, it it possible to have a two or more window functions interacting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SUM(Revenue - Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) AS TotalProfit
```

Or:

```
SUM(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR) - SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR) as TotalProfit
```

These are not exactly the same -- and either could be off due to `NULL` values.  Probably the safest method is:

```
SUM(COALESCE(Revenue, 0) - COALESCE(Cost, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) AS TotalProfit
```

Comment: Huh, why didn't I think of that. Thanks for the answer. I should've asked the full question above. Follow-up question... With a `GROUP BY` I can use this `SUM(Revenue) - SUM(Quantity) * AVG(UnitCost)`. How would this work for a partition? `SUM(Revenue - Quantity * AVG(UnitPrice))` gives me an error.

Comment: @Ivan . . . You can use this with `group by`.  The most likely method would be `sum(sum(revenue - cost)) . . .`, but you might want to ask another question.